# Microsoft Face API - 400 Request Body is invalid

Tags: jquery, azure, electron, face-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I am using the Microsoft Face API to build a Facial recognition desktop app using Electron. I can right now detect a face and create a person group, but run into this error when I try and add a person to my person group:

```
{"error":{"code":"BadArgument","message":"Request body is invalid."}},
```

which is marked as Error 400. Bad request on my console.

This is the [API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039523c) page on how to use this request:

Here is my code, obviously something is wrong with the Data field, but when I use the exact same data in the westCentralUS test server, it is successful. I have tried using and omitting the optional userData field, with a string and an image file.

```
function createPerson() {

var params = {
        // Request parameters
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/persongroups/students/persons",
        beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
            // Request headers
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key",apiKey);
        },
        type: "POST",
        // Request body
        data: { name: "John",}
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        alert("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("error");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
data: JSON.stringify({name: "John"})
```

instead.

Comment: Thank you! That was it. I knew it was something small like that.